# Change mouse cursor inside all of Inno Setup Controls

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

How to change the cursor while it is inside the Inno Setup's area on all controls when the wizard window shows up? I mean like a skin, when the Inno Setup is showing and available the skin is visible. So I mean when the mouse is inside the Inno Setup, it has its own design.

I tried to use this but I do not know where to invoke and using it:

```pascal
procedure SetControlCursor(Control: TControl; Cursor: TCursor);
var 
  I: Integer;
begin
  Control.Cursor := Cursor;
  if Control is TWinControl then
  begin
    for I := 0 to TWinControl(Control).ControlCount - 1 do
    begin
      SetControlCursor(TWinControl(Control).Controls[I], Cursor);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change a cursor of all controls on start, just call your `SetControlCursor` from `InitializeWizard`:

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  SetControlCursor(WizardForm, crHourGlass);
end;
```

*Though, I do not understand why would you want to do that.*

Comment: I'm doing this, because I'm using a skin, so if the cursor changes it would be better.
How can I load my own cursor then?

Comment: You cannot set a completely custom cursor using your `SetControlCursor` function. You can only change the cursor to some standard one. That's why your question does not make sense. Your question does not even mention that you want to use some custom cursor.